# Github Action flake8 fails: f-string is missing placeholders

Tags: python, docker, tdd, testdriven.io

Following the course "FastAPI-TDD with Docker" I got the project to build and pass locally, then in the github action it fails:

It seems the offensive line in the source is:

```
    response = test_app_with_db.get(f"/summaries/")
```

and the Github Action result is:

```
Run docker exec fastapi-tdd python -m flake8 .
  docker exec fastapi-tdd python -m flake8 .
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    IMAGE: docker.pkg.github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/web
./app/db.py:14:1: E303 too many blank lines (3)
./tests/test_ping.py:4:1: F401 'app.main' imported but unused
./tests/test_summaries.py:6:1: F401 'pytest' imported but unused
./tests/test_summaries.py:60:37: F541 f-string is missing placeholders
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 20):

f string work with place holder
Example :
If you want to put '/summary/' in f string assign it to some variable then put that variable in place holder

Syntax is

```
f'{variable}'
```

Example :

```
f'{"quoted string"}'
```

Answer (score 15):

I got the error on my when checking my code with flake8. The problem its simply that I was using a f-string for something that could be just a string.

f-string make sense when you insert variables for example:

**Correct use of f-string**

```
age = 34
print(f'Hi my name is Enrique and my age is {age} years old')
```

but if you are just puting a string withou variables then you are making a wrong use of f-string

**Incorrect use of f-string**

```
print(f'Hi my name is Enrique and my age is 34 years old')
```

In that case you don´t need to use the f-string as you are not inserting any variable in your string

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue following the course `Test-Driven Development with Django, Django REST Framework, and Docker`.

I determined that a different version of `flake8` was running locally vs during my GitHub Action.

I checked locally by running (within the docker container)...

```
flake8 --version
```

...and compared that output to the logs for my GitHub Action.

In my case, `flake8 3.7.9` was running in the local container, but the GitHub Action was using `flake8 3.8.4`.

Looks like a new `pyflakes` check for `F541` made it into `flake8 3.8.0` (see https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/issues/648)

As for a fix, I see two options:

1. convert f-strings without placeholders in the source to string literals
2. force `flake8 3.7.9` during the GitHub Action

for example, in `Dockerfile.prod`...

`RUN pip install black flake8==3.7.9 isort`

...allowed my build to finish successfully. It seems better to upgrade `flake8` though and make the source comply with `F541`.

---

I tried for awhile to understand why...

`RUN pip install black flake8 isort`

...wouldn't use the previously-created wheels for those packages (see `Dockerfile.prod` below).

My guess is that the instruction to install and run linters during the `builder` stage can't use the previously-created wheels for those linters because said wheels were built with `--no-deps`. I presume that `pip` falls back to searching the online index in that case and lacking other instructions installs the latest available version. Since my `Dockerfile` differs materially from my `Dockerfile.prod` in this area, I conclude that this gives rise to a different version of `flake8` running locally vs during my GitHub Action.

`Dockerfile.prod`:

```
#Builder

FROM python:3.8.2-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install black flake8 isort
RUN flake8 .
RUN black --exclude=migrations .
RUN isort ./*/*.py

#Final

FROM python:3.8.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBUG 0
ENV SECRET_KEY foo
ENV DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1] .herokuapp.com

RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

RUN adduser -D myuser
RUN chown myuser /usr/src/app
USER myuser

CMD gunicorn drf_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Answer (score 1):

./app/db.py:14:1: E303 too many blank lines (3) ./tests/test_ping.py:4:1: F401 'app.main' imported but unused ./tests/test_summaries.py:6:1: F401 'pytest' imported but unused

I can see some extra error too which will again make your build fail in ci test run

From line 14 you need to remove extra line
From line 4 and 6 you imported app.main and pytest which is unused in your code so need to remove that too